# Simple Bread Crumb with regex

Tags: regex, breadcrumbs

I am trying to create a simple bread crumb with regex by splitting a given URL:

Input is a URL in this form - http://someurl.com:1000/sites/Site1/Pages/Programs/Programs1/Programs2/SomePage.aspx?a=b;c=d

Output expected is - 
You are here: sites>Site1>Pages>Programs>Programs1>Programs2>SomePage

And here is the code I have used:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var url ="http://someurl:1000/sites/Site1/Pages/Programs/Programs1/Programs2/SomePage.aspx?a=b;c=d"


var newURL = url.replace(new RegExp( "^(?:([^:/?#]+):)?(?://((?:(([^:@]*):?([^:@]*))?@)?([^:/?#]*)(?::(\\d*))?))?((((?:[^?#/]*/)*)([^?#]*))(?:\\?([^#]*))?(?:#(.*))?)", "g"),

  function( $0, $1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8, $9){

  var domain = $1+ "://" + $2;
  var href = domain;
  var urlStrippedDown = $9;

  //Split the folders/pages within the path     /sites/Site1/Pages/Programs/Programs1/Programs2/SomePage.aspx
  var pieces = urlStrippedDown.replace( new RegExp (\\w+.aspx)|(\\w+),


  //Form the bread crumb with anchor tags and text
  function ($0, $1, $2)
  {

    zero = $0;
    var test =  "<a href='" + href +     urlStrippedDown.substring(0,urlStrippedDown.indexOf($0)+$0.length) +"'>" +     zero.replace('.aspx','')  + "</a>";
    return test;
  }
  );

  return pieces;
  }
);


//document.write("You are here: " + newURL.replace(/\//g,''));
document.write("You are here: " + newURL);

</script>
```

Problem faced:
The only issue I am facing is that the final output (newURL) has a forward slash ("/") between each link, that I would like to replace with ">" but this seems to be impossible. I am not sure how this "/" is getting inserted, though its not showing it as part of text when the "anchor" tag is formed.

The expected output is- You are here: sites>Site1>Pages>Programs>Programs1>Programs2>SomePage

whereas I get- You are here: /sites/Site1/Pages/Programs/Programs1/Programs2/SomePage 
and I am unable to replace this "/" with ">"

P.S: The commented line of code - If I replace here, it replaces all "/" even those inside the anchor tags. The "/" should be replaced in the text and not in the href of the anchor

Is there a flaw in the regex? Are there better ways to handle this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first replace doesn't really serve any other purpose than to split the string into to parts: domain and the path, instead you should consider using `RegExp.exec` on the string and get the parts that way (see snippet below).

Your `newURL` variable contains the html, which you can take advantage of and use in your regex. If you replace all `/<a` with `&gt; <a` you should have a string as such: `> sites > Site1 > Pages > Programs > Programs1 > Programs2 > SomePage`. And then you would have to remove the first `>` as I would imagine you don't want that.

Your regex seems overly complex for what you need for your first match, and your second replace you might be better of doing using a `indexOf('/')` and a loop instead since you're not really leveraging on the regex matches.

Below you'll find a function to make the desired link chain for an arbitrary valid URI using a similar approach to your initial solution. I have this as a result of tinkering with your code so it seems a waste to not post it.

```
var url = "http://someurl:1000/sites/Site1/Pages/Programs/Programs1/Programs2/SomePage.aspx?a=b;c=d";

function makeBreadcrumb(url){
    // Split match and split url into domain and path.
    var urlSplitter = new RegExp("^(.*?://[^/]+?/)([^?#:@]*)", "");
    var matcher;
    if (matcher = urlSplitter.exec(url)) {
        var domain = matcher[1];
        // Match every "folder" or "file" in the URI and replace with "breadcrumb link".
        return matcher[2].replace(new RegExp("([^/]+)(?:\\.[^\\.]+$|/)","g"),
            function(match,dir,pos,string) {
                return (pos > 0 ? " > " : "") + "<a href=\"" + domain + string.substring(0,pos) + match + "\">" + dir + "</a>";
            }
        );
    }
    return "";
}

document.write("You are here: " + makeBreadcrumb(url));
```

Comment: Agree that the one I used was overly complex. This kind of servers my purpose. Thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 0):

Try This pattern it select all your "\" symbols as your requirement replace them what ever you want

```
(\/)(?=[^\/:]*(\/|$))(?=[^\/])
```

(/)(?=[^/:]*(/|$))   Matches "/" only if "/" is followed by all characters except "/"and : next end with "/" or end of line